# Ace Editor: Can't get rid of Marker

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am writing a simple widget that simulates a simple 8-bit CPU. For that I am abusing the Ace Editor, as you can see at the center of the image, as my "*RAM*"-view.

[image]

I want to highlight the line that corresponds to the value of the program counter and I am using `addMarker()` to do so.

However, I can't seem to get rid of that marker once I have set it. `_marker` is a private member that holds the value of the last marker set. But for some reason `removeMarker(_marker)` has no effect:

```
/**
 *
 */
setMarker: function(position) {

    //if(_marker != null) {
        window.cpuRamView.session.removeMarker(_marker);
    //}

    _marker = new window.Range(position, 0, position, _content[position].length);

    window.cpuRamView.session.addMarker(
        _marker, "programCounterLocation", "fullLine"
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? :/

Comment: Have you finished that project? Sound like an interesting one.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Well, yes I finished it but I don't think I'd find the project - it was just for an exercise on the university. However, it's rather simple to get something like that running assuming you know how to translate the code to bytecode and have some basic knowledge about either assembly or how a cpu works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add marker returns an id, and removeMarker requires that id, so you can do something like

```
var Range = require("ace/range").Range // not the window Range!!
var _range

setMarker = function(position) {

    if(_range != null) {
        window.cpuRamView.session.removeMarker(_range.id);
    }

    _range = new Range(position, 0, position, _content[position].length);

    _range.id = window.cpuRamView.session.addMarker(
        _range, "programCounterLocation", "fullLine"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.marker) {
        this.editor.getSession().removeMarker(this.marker);
      }
      this.marker = this.editor.getSession().addMarker(
        new Range(prop('errorLine')(formulaError), prop('errorPosition')(formulaError), prop('errorLine')(formulaError), prop('errorPosition')(formulaError) + 5), style.errorMarker, 'text');
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a short text description to allow us to understand your answer by itself, without going back-and-forth to the question.

Answer (score 0):

set a variable `marker` to receive the return value, just like this:

```
marker=editor.session.addMarker(range, "myMarker", "fullLine");
```

and then remove this marker, like this:

```
editor.session.removeMarker(marker);
```